# Search a catalog for matching values and getting a 3rd column as a result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have 2 columns A and B that contain Country and State/City. This is a spreadsheet called Data,
I have another spreadsheet called Catalog that contains the Country and City along side different data on the following columns. I want to search the combination of both A column and B column and obtain C value of Catalog

I could have data like:

```
A    |       B       |     C     |   D
USA  | Washington DC |   23423   |   DC
USA  |    Maryland   |   23421   |   MD
```

I want to get C or D from the catalog spreadsheet

In the data catalog I would have:

```
A    |       B       |     C    
USA  | Washington DC |  Run Function(A1:B1, Catalog!A2:B222)
USA  |    Maryland   |  Run Function(A2:B2, Catalog!A2:B222)
```

Using Bard, I've gotten this function:

```
function searchCatalog(rangeOfData, rangeOfCatalog) {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Get the values in the range of data.
  var dataValues = spreadsheet.getRange(rangeOfData).getValues();
  // Get the values in the range of catalog.
  var catalogValues = spreadsheet.getRange(rangeOfCatalog).getValues();
  // Iterate over the rows in the catalog.
  for (var i = 0; i < catalogValues.length; i++) {
    // If the data matches the catalog, return the code.
    if (dataValues[0] == catalogValues[i][0] && dataValues[1] == catalogValues[i][1]) {
      return catalogValues[i][2];
    }
  }
  // If the data does not match the catalog, return None.
  return 'None';
}
```

I keep getting **Range not found**

Comment: Share an image or a table of your data and your catalog

Comment: Share the values of the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script and your 2 tables and your question, if `Run Function(A1:B1, Catalog!A2:B222)` is `searchCatalog(A1:B1, Catalog!A2:B222)`, the values of `A1:B1` and `Catalog!A2:B222` are given as the 2-dimensional arrays. But, your script uses them as the range. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue of `I keep getting Range not found`.
- And, in your expected result, you want to retrieve the value of column "C" of "Catalog" sheet. But, your custom function uses only columns "A" and "B". I think that this might be your 2nd issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function searchCatalog(rangeOfData, rangeOfCatalog) {
  const values = rangeOfCatalog.find(([a, b]) => [a, b].join("") == rangeOfData[0].join(""));
  return values ? values[2] : "None";
}
```

- In this case, please put a custom function of `=searchCatalog(A1:B1, Catalog!A2:C222)` into a cell. By this, this script is run and the value is returned. When your showing 2 tables are used, `=searchCatalog(A1:B1, Catalog!A2:C222)` returns `23423`.
- If you want to use your showing script, in this case, it is required to give the vlues as the string like `=searchCatalog("A1:B1", "Catalog!A2:C222")`. Please modify it as follows.

  ```js
  function searchCatalog(rangeOfData, rangeOfCatalog) {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    // Get the values in the range of data.
    var dataValues = spreadsheet.getRange(rangeOfData).getValues()[0]; // Modified
    // Get the values in the range of catalog.
    var catalogValues = spreadsheet.getRange(rangeOfCatalog).getValues();
    // Iterate over the rows in the catalog.
    for (var i = 0; i < catalogValues.length; i++) {
      // If the data matches the catalog, return the code.
      if (dataValues[0] == catalogValues[i][0] && dataValues[1] == catalogValues[i][1]) {
        return catalogValues[i][2];
      }
    }
    // If the data does not match the catalog, return None.
    return 'None';
  }
  ```
- As another pattern, when you want to retrieve the result values using one custom function, how about the following sample script? In this case, please put a custom function of `=searchCatalog(A1:B, Catalog!A2:C222)` into a cell. By this, the script is run.

  ```js
  function searchCatalog(rangeOfData, rangeOfCatalog) {
    const obj = rangeOfData.map(r => r.join(""));
    return rangeOfCatalog.map(([a, b, c]) => obj.includes([a, b].join("")) ? c : "None");
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function searchCatalog(rangeOfData = "Sheet0!A2:P22", rangeOfCatalog = "Sheet1!A2:P22") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var vs = ss.getRange(rangeOfData).getValues();
  var cs = ss.getRange(rangeOfCatalog).getValues();
  var o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == cs[i][0] && r[1] == cs[i][1]) {
      return [cs[i][2]];
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  if(o && o.length > 0) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
    return o;
  }
}
```

Sheets 0 and 1 both has same data to guarantee output

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 6 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 7 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 8 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 9 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 10 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 11 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 12 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 13 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| 14 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| 15 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |
| 16 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| 17 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 |
| 18 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 |
| 19 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 |
| 20 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 |
| 21 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 |
| 22 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 |

The output is the third column

```
[[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]]
```